# How to add a column to a DBGrid by code?

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

Using a `TDBGrid`, I want to add a new column and set its name by code.

How to do this at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TColumn` class doesn't have a `Name` property. Note that it doesn't inherits from `TComponent` (`TColumn` -> `TCollectionItem` -> `TPersistent` -> `TObject`) and its parent classes don't add any `Name` property.

Anyhow, you can add a new column to a `TDBGrid` by simply calling the `Add` method of the `Columns` collection:

```
var
  Col : TColumn;
begin
  Col := DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
  //then you can set its properties as your needs
  Col.Title.Caption := 'MyNewColumn';
end;
```

Comment: @Johnny: You're welcome, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it solved the problem

Comment: If I create a column in a RxDBGrid after dataset is loaded, it shows the new column, but all other columns disappear. Do you maybe know why? 
I need both columns dynamically loaded from dataset and new column dynamically created through code....